# problems with certificate x.509 c#

Tags: c#, certificate, app-config, x509

I have seen several questions related to this issue, and I have tried a lot of the ideas presented in them with no success.

Here are my situations:

FIRST:

When I write in app.config something like this:

```
    <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="1234*********"
            x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" 
            storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" />
      </clientCredentials>
     </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Than I saw that kind of communicate:
"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

SECOND:

```
     <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="test"
            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" 
            storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" />
      </clientCredentials>
     </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Than I see that kind of communicate :
It's to many certificate with that name.

I install my certificate by mmc in local computer and this certificate is in trusted publish root. Also i check if IE has this certificate and also have.

I tried search my certificate by thumb print, by subject name, issuer name, serial number, subject key identifier and nothing.

UPDATE:
I found the solution!All you need to add is:

BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

```
        basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

        basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://testasp.asmx");

        RemoteSetup.RemoteSetupServiceSoapClient client = new RemoteSetup.RemoteSetupServiceSoapClient(basicHttpBinding, endpoint);

        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

        client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Comment: format your code properly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a kind of similar problem and done something like this:
First registered to `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` event:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
```

Then manually checked for persistent and returned `true`:

```
private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, 
                                X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (cert.Subject.ToUpper().Contains("MY_CERT_ISSUER_NAME"))
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I didn't found any "correct" solutions, this one is not quietly best, but may help.